# Set C++ variable from Python script using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm having issues setting a variable in C++ using SWIG and Python. I have a class with a variable and a get and set function, which are all static.
What I'm trying to do is to set the static variable in the Python script, but as soon as it leaves the PyRun_SimpleFile function, the variable is set back to it's original value.

So how can I set variables in C++ using Python/SWIG?

**minimal.h**

```
    class Minimal
{
public:
    static int Minimal::var;
    static int Minimal::GetVar() { return var; }
    void Minimal::SetVar(int x){ var = x; }
};
```

**minimal.i**

```
%module minimal

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "minimal.h"
%}

%include "minimal.h"
```

**Python Script**

```
import minimal

m1 = minimal.Minimal()

m1.SetVar(10)
```

**Call to Python script**

```
// Initialize Python
    Py_Initialize();

    // Perform Python actions here.
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('../Python')");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('../Python/Scripts')");

    fp = _Py_fopen(directory, "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, directory);

    Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: Your minimal example is missing any calls to  PyRun_SimpleFile so it's kind of tricky to do more than guess what the problem is. Likely you're reloading the shared object with the static variable in it each time though. Can you show a little more context about that bit please?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it. I'm not really experienced with SWIG, so I don't know how to share data with Python and C++. I know that I create a new object in Python everytime, but changing a static variable should be the same for every object right?

Comment: Remember that the 'static' instances initialized and modified using PyRun_SimpleFile are different from the instance linked to by your c program.

Comment: @JensMunk That makes sense, but I'm not sure what the solution would be. Is there a simple way to exchange variables from C++ to Python and back?